# Returns null from edited cell of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I create a simple DataGrid with editable cells in WPF. But i am getting null data from the edited cell. I am newbie in WPF. What is the problem?

When I attempt to change the Folder cell, it is changed as seen
[in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuOd0.jpg).

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsOik.jpg)!

The Codes,

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Product> tmpProducts = new List<Product>();

            tmpProducts.Add(new Product {
                id = 1, title = "Product A", folder = null,
            });
            tmpProducts.Add(new Product {
                id = 2,  title = "Product B", folder = null,
            });

            productGrid.ItemsSource = tmpProducts;
        }

        private void selectFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // selected folder from dialog, etc. then,
            string selectedPath = "C:\\myFolder";

            object item = productGrid.SelectedItem;
            (productGrid.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text = selectedPath;
        }

        private void updateProducts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < productGrid.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Product prd = (Product)productGrid.Items[i];
                Console.WriteLine(prd.folder);
            }
        }
    }


    class Product
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string folder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```js
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="productGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="0,0,0,36">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="ID"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding title}" Header="Title" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding folder}" Header="Foler" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Click="selectFolder" Content="Browse.." Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Click="updateProducts" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the "folder" property of your products to null and then you are never setting it again. You are just changing the text of the DataGridCell. You need to set the folder property of your products as well before you try to get it on the updateProducts event. Like this:

```
private void selectFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // selected folder from dialog, etc. then,
    string selectedPath = "C:\\myFolder";

    object item = productGrid.SelectedItem;

    (item as Product).folder = selectedPath; //set the folder property of your Product item

    (productGrid.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text = selectedPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `folder` property of the corresponding `Product` object instead of setting the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`:

```
private void selectFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    Product product = btn.DataContext as Product;
    string selectedPath = "C:\\myFolder";
    product.folder = selectedPath;
}
```

Note that for you to be able to see the new value in the `DataGrid`, the `Product` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the folder property:

```
class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    private string _folder;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _folder; }
        set { _folder = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am newbie in WPF, I will try MVVM way too.